# What are the various technical specs of a fast charging cable?

Tags: usb, charging

## What technical specs do I need to look for to know a cable will be compatible with my phone?

I just bought a new Motorola G7 supra and none of my existing USB type C cables work with it. I plug it in and nothing happens, no data connection and no power connection.

I don't know if it is USB speed, amperage rating / wire gauge or something else. 
Also I want to know all the the technical specs so that when I buy a spare cable I can get one at least as good as the one that came with it.

This information is helpful yet does not seem to answer my question. 
**How does fast charging work? Here’s every single standard compared**
https://www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/how-does-fast-charging-work/

Comment: Modern USB-C chargers use USB power delivery (USB-PD). For fast charging higher ampere and higher voltage levels are possible. What levels you need depends on what the Smartphone supports.

Comment: Tech specs, simply speaking is that the cable supports fast charging. But it's not as easy as that, it depends on many factors, see a [selection of answers that address](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A131553++OEM+cable)

Comment: You can compare the [specs](https://www.amazon.com/Bemz-USB-C-Cable-Compatible-Power/dp/B07NJ6B9KG). Best is to check in Lenovo forums